# android: how do I check if dialogfragment is showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I launch my dialog fragment using

```
FragmentTransaction ft = 
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment()
dialog.show(ft, "dialog");
```

then to get a handle on it I do

```
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
```

but once I get `prev`, how do I check if it is showing?

**Back Story**

My problem is that my looping code keeps launching the dialog again and again. But if the dialog is already showing, I don't want it to launch again.
This back story is just for context. The answer I seek is not: "move it out of the loop."

Comment: Call prev.isVisible(). See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible()

Comment: By calling  dialogFragment.getShowsDialog()

Answer (score 36, accepted):

simply check if it's null

```
if(prev == null)
    //There is no active fragment with tag "dialog"
else
    //There is an active fragment with tag "dialog" and "prev" variable holds a reference to it.
```

Alternatively, you could check the activity the fragment `prev` is currently associated with, however, make sure you ask that **after** you make sure it's not null or you'll get a NullPointerException. Like this:

```
if(prev == null)
    //There is no active fragment with tag "dialog"
else
    if(prev.getActivity() != this) //additional check
        //There is a fragment with tag "dialog", but it is not active (shown) which means it was found on device's back stack.
    else
        //There is an active fragment with tag "dialog"
```

Comment: This doesn't always work, for example if the dialog has just been dismissed. I ran into this problem when I sometimes wanted to show a dialog immediately after it was dismissed (I reused the same fragment to show a "different" dialog). The solution I found to be working is the same as by @j2emanue below. `if (fragment.getDialog() == null || !fragment.getDialog().isShowing()) { fragment.show(fragmentManager, tag); }` (in my case I already know that my fragment is not null).

Answer (score 156):

```
 if (dialogFragment != null
     && dialogFragment.getDialog() != null
     && dialogFragment.getDialog().isShowing()
     && !dialogFragment.isRemoving()) {
            //dialog is showing so do something 
 } else {
     //dialog is not showing
 }
```

UPDATE: team can you also try the below call,  i think it will work logically:

```
dialogFragment.isResumed
```

that should mean its in the foreground displaying if im not mistaken.

Comment: Wonderful! Worked!  `dialog.isVisible()` is the real culprit which, sometimes says `false` even when dialog is visible!! So, `dialogFragment.getDialog().isShowing()` worked..like a charm!

Comment: This works as intended, and should be the accepted answer, but gets placed last...

Comment: If dialogFragment happens to be null, dialogFragment.getDialog() will give a null pointer exception.

Comment: If you call DialogFragment's creation several times in one moment, `dialogFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");` will return null, and all dialogs will be shown.

Comment: Would it help if `dialogFragment.isRemoving() == false` is also added to this check?

Comment: @rpattabi that seems like a god idea. i updated the post.

Comment: @j2emanue Your decision to keep `isRemoving` check at the end is interesting and makes sense.

Comment: is removing is not exist more?

Comment: dialogFragment != null is always false

Comment: But if you click the button too fast, the dilagFragment will come up twice.

Comment: Just use a throttle on the click event. Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221410/835883

Comment: Also by calling  dialogFragment.getShowsDialog()

Comment: Yea this still doesn't work as a check to see if the dialog is already showing if you call .show() twice one right after the other.

Answer (score 57):

I added this to be inside my custom dialog fragment, so I don't have to worry about any logic on the outside.  Override the `show()` and `onDismiss()` methods, with a `boolean shown` field:

```
  private static boolean shown = false;

    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        if (shown) return;

        super.show(manager, tag);
        shown = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        shown = false;
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
```

If you want to check whether it is shown or not, you can create a getter for the `shown` boolean.

Comment: Not the best answer, If user receive call while dialog is showing the dialog will added twice because variable `show` will created again with value `false`, You must to make `show` variable `static`,   `private static boolean shown = false;`

Comment: +1 for the previous comment and also: this approach is not applicable if you create a new instance from the outside for each dialog invocation. One could argue that you could make "shown" static but I think this would have other implications

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51934699/2914140: in `void show(…)` change line: `if (shown || manager.isStateSaved()) return;`.

Comment: You're also going to want to override onCancel and set shown = false there or dismissing by tapping outside of dialog won't call onDismiss and "shown" will remain stuck on true.  I tried to edit the answer but the edit queue is full.

Answer (score 3):

100% Uptime

```
class ProgressDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

 companion object {
    private val TAG = this::class.simpleName
 }

 lateinit var dialogFragmentManager: FragmentManager
 
 fun showDialog() {
    dialogFragmentManager.apply {
       if (findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) show(this, TAG) else return
    }
 }

}

lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialogFragment
```

---

Init:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   
    initProgressDialog(supportFragmentManager)
}

fun initProgressDialog(fragmentManager: FragmentManager){
    progressDialog = ProgressDialogFragment().apply {
        dialogFragmentManager = fragmentManager
    }
}
```

---

Use { *progressDialog.showDialog()* } everywhere

Comment: This is gonna be disappointing to you "great" finding but just call `progressDialog.showDialog()` twice back-to-back and you will get two dialogs. Because `show` is asynchronous and your `findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null` check will be true until dialog is actually added by system.

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin style:

```
private fun showDialog(dialogFragment: DialogFragment, tag: String) {
    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag).let { fragment ->
        fragment ?: let {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().let { transition ->
                dialogFragment.show(transition, tag)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this problem is not even solved technically so there is no need to jam in your Kotlin "solution"