# Preventing rapid clicks with RXJava

Tags: rx-java

I am writing an android app and using rxjava to handle user input events.  Basically what I want to do is, emit when a button is clicked, and then drop subsequent emissions for some period of time afterwards (like a second or two), essentially to prevent having to process multiple clicks of the button.

Comment: If you don't necessarily want to drop for some period of time, but rather drop as long as the processing is going on, you can [take advantage of the backpressure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52966919/1916449).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `throttleFirst` is what you want: https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#wiki-throttlefirst

Comment: Here is an example especially for this purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35705364/1732338

Answer (score 3):

For preventing fast clicks i use this code

```
RxView.clicks(your_view)
            .throttleFirst(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe {
                //on click
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Continuing zsxwing's Answer:

If you're not using **RxBinding** library but only **RxJava** then,

```
io.reactivex.Observable.just(view_obj)
                .throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)// prevent rapid click for 1 seconds
                .blockingSubscribe(o -> {                     
                    startActivity(...);
                });
```

Comment: The blockingSubscribe never gets called.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with share debounce and buffer operator

```
Observable<Object> tapEventEmitter = _rxBus.toObserverable().share();
Observable<Object> debouncedEventEmitter = tapEventEmitter.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable<List<Object>> debouncedBufferEmitter = tapEventEmitter.buffer(debouncedEventEmitter);

debouncedBufferEmitter.buffer(debouncedEventEmitter)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<List<Object>>() {
      @Override
      public void call(List<Objecenter code heret> taps) {
        _showTapCount(taps.size());
      }
    });
```