# Android: dialogFragment.isVisible() not working

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm dealing with the dismiss/stateLoss hell when using `DialogFragment`. To avoid invalid dismisses I'm overriding the `dismiss` method:

```
@Override
public void dismiss() {
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        super.dismiss();
    }
}
```

But `isVisible()` is `false` even when the dialog is in fact visible. This is what the `isVisible()` method says in its documentation:

> Return true if the fragment is currently visible to the user. This
>   means it: (1) has been added, (2) has its view attached to the window,
>   and (3) is not hidden.

So if I change the method to:

```
@Override
public void dismiss() {
    // This is almost the same as isVisible(), but the latter doesn't
    // work
    if (this.isAdded() && !this.isDetached() && !this.isHidden()) {
        super.dismiss();
    }
}
```

then it works perfectly. Is this expected behaviour?

Everything is executed after an HTTP request using [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion):

```
DialogFragment dialog = DialogFragment.newInstance(..., ...);

Ion.with(context, url)
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
});

dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Comment: post the code where you call the dismiss

Comment: Actually, it says 'has its view attached' which is very different from that you check with isDetached(). Check out Fragment.isVisible() source in platform sources in your sdk installation.

Comment: Seems it is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24412988/753575)